# How to obtain warning for forgotten cast in arithmetic?

Tags: c++, c, gcc-warning

Consider this situation:

```
uint64_t add(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
   return a + b; // programmer neglected (uint64_t) a + b.
}
```

How do we get the C or C++ front-end of GCC (or of any other compiler) to warn about this situation: that an operation is being done in a narrow type that is immediately widened?

I've read through the current GCC documentation, and tried various warnings like `-Wconversion`, but nothing.

Comment: I'd also tag the language.  This is either C or C++, I'm not sure which, otherwise I'd tag it myself.  :(

Comment: @Amy Good point. In my specific case, I don't care. My project compiles as either C or C++, for various motivations one of which is that I can (and do) take advantage of C++ diagnostics.

Comment: I don't think GCC alone can help here. Some kind of static analyzer perhaps.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You sure? It's a very simple static test to a localized area of the abstract syntax tree: an expression performing 32 bit calculation widened to 64 bit result.   The issue `double a = b/c` where `b` and `c` are integers, where the programmer intended floating-point division, could similarly be diagnosed.  The left operand of an assignment is `double`, and the right is a `/` operator node of integer type: boom, warn.

Comment: The intention of the programmer here is not transparent. He might be very well interested in wrapped-around result as well, which is completely valid and not that uncommon.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The intention is transparent if I apply this `-W<whatever>` when compiling a specific source file; I want to be warned about all such cases, and don't care about false positives. All sorts of compiler warnings can be false positive nuisances. A `switch` case fall-through can be intentional, yet we have a warning for that now as well as ways of indicating intent. (GCC can actually read `/* fallthrough */` comments now: TIL).  I'm willing to review 150 cases of this reported by the compiler, if just one bug is found.

Comment: This can question can be only answered positively by providing the requested option. The negative answer "there is no such an option" will always have a degree of doubt. Well, I (and you) have looked through the documentation and haven't found it.

Comment: And to make sure, what are you expecting to be warned about here? The possible wrap-around or an implicit conversion from `uint32_t` to `uint64_t`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't care what the wording is about, it can just say `"foo.c:32: code smell identified"`. The ideal situation for the warning is the combination of the two: the possibility of overflow in the calculation which goes away if the calculation is done in the type that is capturing the result.

Comment: if you said `any other compiler`, why did you tag only gcc? And if you're only interested in unsigned overflow then an appropriate tag is also needed. Otherwise without the code it looks like you also want warnings for signed operations like `int x, y; long long z = x + y;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. A warning here is suitable and warranted.  It's motivated by precisely the same concerns as long = int * int, and float = int / int.  These are easy mistakes to make, even for experienced programmers.  The compiler-writer's insistence that expressions must always be evaluated "inside out" does not match the way people think.  A destination type significantly different than the type of the type on the rhs is a good indication of the programmer's likely intent.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a flag to GCC that will cause a warning. The Coverity static analyzer will issue an [OVERFLOW_BEFORE_WIDEN](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/Coverity) warning as this is flagged in the CERT standards.

Disclaimer: I once worked for Coverity.

Comment: Interesting. As luck would have it, the free Coverity Scan service for open source projects has just gone belly up days ago due to external factors: https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Coverity-Scan-Update

Answer (score 1):

Since the code I'm working with compiles as C or C++, and the types in question are all typedefs (which are easily retargeted to classes), it occurs to me that a C++ solution is possible. The following code sample hints at the idea:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

template <typename outer, typename inner, typename underlying> class arith {
public:
  underlying val;

  arith(underlying v) : val(v) { }
  explicit operator underlying () const { return val; }
  outer operator +(const inner &rhs) { return val + rhs.val; }
};

struct narrow;

struct narrow_result : public arith<narrow_result, narrow_result, uint32_t> {
  narrow_result(uint32_t v) : arith(v) { }
  narrow_result(const narrow &v);
};

struct narrow : public arith<narrow_result, narrow, uint32_t> {
  narrow(uint32_t v) : arith(v) { }
  narrow(const narrow_result &v) : arith(v.val) { }
};

inline narrow_result::narrow_result(const narrow &v)
: arith(v.val)
{
}

struct wide {
  uint64_t val;

  wide(uint64_t v) : val(v) { }
  wide(const narrow &v) : val(v) { }
  operator uint64_t () const { return val; }
  wide operator +(const wide &rhs) { return val + rhs.val; }
};

int main()
{
  narrow a = 42;
  narrow b = 9;
  wide c = wide(a) + b;
  wide d = a + b;          // line 43
  narrow e = a + b;
  wide f = a;              // line 45
  narrow g = a + b + b;    // line 46
  return 0;
}
```

Here, GNU C++ diagnoses only line 43:

```
overflow.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
overflow.cc:43:16: error: conversion from ‘narrow_result’ to non-scalar type ‘wide’ requested
```

Note that a `narrow` to `wide` implicit conversion is still allowed, as seen in line 45, simply because `wide` has a conversion constructor targeting `narrow` directly. It just lacks one for `narrow_result`.

Line 46 shows that we can compound the arithmetic operations. This is possible because `narrow` implicitly converts to `narrow_result` and *vice versa*.  However, this implicit conversion doesn't kick in on line 45; the `narrow_result` of the addition doesn't convert to `narrow` so that this could then convert to `wide`.

This can all be wrapped with `#ifdef __cplusplus` and the presence of a conditional debug macro, that same macro also enabling alternative definitions of the types as typedefs for `narrow` and `wide`. Of course, numerous other arithmetic operations must be supported in the `arith` template base.

Comment: Pardon my C++; it's been over 10 years since I touched a `class` let alone a `template`.

Answer (score 1):

Since *any other compiler* is OK, you can use

- Visual Studio Code Analysis which does a static compile time check
- Clang's `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow` option for runtime check

---

## Visual Studio Code Analysis can do that

It has various checks for integer overflow including unsigned operations

> - [C26450 RESULT_OF_ARITHMETIC_OPERATION_PROVABLY_LOSSY](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/c26450): *[operator]* operation causes overflow at compile time. Use a wider type to store the operands. This warning indicates that an arithmetic operation was provably lossy at compile time. This can be asserted when the operands are all compile-time constants. Currently, we check left shift, multiplication, addition, and subtraction operations for such overflows.
>
>   ```
>   uint32_t multiply()
>   {
>      const uint32_t a = UINT_MAX; // the author used int here 
>      const uint32_t b = 2;        // but I changed to unsigned for this question
>      uint32_t c = a * b; // C26450 reported here [and also C4307]
>      return c;
>   }
>   ```
> - [C26451 RESULT_OF_ARITHMETIC_OPERATION_CAST_TO_LARGER_SIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/c26451): Using operator *[operator]* on a *[size1]* byte value and then casting the result to a *[size2]* byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator *[operator]* to avoid overflow.
>
>   This warning indicates incorrect behavior that results from integral promotion rules and types larger than those in which arithmetic is typically performed. We detect when a narrow type integral value was shifted left, multiplied, added, or subtracted and the result of that arithmetic operation was cast to a wider type value. If the operation overflowed the narrow type value, then data is lost. You can prevent this loss by casting the value to a wider type before the arithmetic operation.
>
>   ```
>   void leftshift(int i) {
>      unsigned long long x;
>      x = i << 31; // C26451 reported here
>           // code
>
>   // Corrected source:
>   void leftshift(int i) {
>       unsigned long long x;
>       x = (unsigned long long)i << 31; // OK
>           // code
>   }
>   ```
> - [C26454 RESULT_OF_ARITHMETIC_OPERATION_NEGATIVE_UNSIGNED](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/c26454): *[operator]* operation wraps past 0 and produces a large unsigned number at compile time
>
>   This warning indicates that the subtraction operation produces a negative result which was evaluated in an unsigned context. This causes the result to wrap past 0 and produce a really large unsigned number, which can result in unintended overflows.
>
>   ```
>   // Example source:
>   unsigned int negativeunsigned() {
>       const unsigned int x = 1u - 2u; // C26454 reported here
>       return x;
>   }
>
>   // Corrected source:
>   unsigned int negativeunsigned() {
>       const unsigned int x = 4294967295; // OK
>       return x;
>   }
>   ```
>
> ### [Arithmetic overflow checks in C++ Core Check](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/arithmetic-overflow-checks-in-c-core-check/)

Here's an example of it in action

[image: MSVC static code analysis result]

As you can see from the examples above, the compiler itself can also emit a warning if the operands were compile time constants. If they were variables then you need the static analyzer

You can play around with that on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+func(uint64_t+y)%0A%7B%0A++++(void)y%3B%0A%7D%0Avoid+callsomefunc(uint32_t+x,+uint32_t+y)%0A%7B%0A++++func(x+*+2)%3B++++++++++++++++++++//+C26451%0A++++const+uint64_t+d+%3D+x+%2B+y%3B+++++++//+C26451%0A++++const+uint64_t+e+%3D+x+-+y%3B%0A++++const+uint64_t+f+%3D+x+*+y%3B+++++++//+C26451%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char+**argv)%0A%7B%0A++++const+uint64_t+a+%3D+1U+%3C%3C+32%3B+++//+C4293,+C6297,+C26452%0A++++const+uint64_t+b+%3D+1+%3C%3C+32%3B++++//+C4293,+C6297,+C26452%0A++++const+uint64_t+c+%3D+1+%3C%3C+31%3B++++//+C6297,+C26451%0A%0A++++const+uint32_t+d+%3D+0x12345678U+*+0xDEFU%3B++++//+C4307,+C26450%0A++++const+uint64_t+e+%3D+0xFFFFFFFFU+%2B+2U%3B++++++++//+C4307,+C26450%0A++++const+uint64_t+f+%3D+1U+-+2U%3B+++++//+C26454%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.48563968668407,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_16_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:/analyze,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x64+msvc+v19.16+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:53.40136054421768,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:3,editor:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%233+with+x64+msvc+v19.16%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.59863945578232,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:61.51436031331591,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), although I'm not sure how to make it really work from command line. If you know how to pass arguments to VS code analysis please comment below. On MSVC GUI just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

For information on how to run the analysis read [C++ Static Analysis Improvements for Visual Studio 2017 15.6 Preview 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-static-analysis-improvements-for-visual-studio-2017-15-6-preview-2/)

---

**Clang** doesn't have a *compile-time* option for that, but it has an option to check at runtime

> `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`: Unsigned integer overflow, where the result of an unsigned integer computation cannot be represented in its type. Unlike signed integer overflow, this is not undefined behavior, but it is often unintentional. This sanitizer does not check for lossy implicit conversions performed before such a computation (see `-fsanitize=implicit-conversion`).
>
> [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#available-checks)

It can also be disabled easily

> ### [Silencing Unsigned Integer Overflow](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#silencing-unsigned-integer-overflow)
>
> To silence reports from unsigned integer overflow, you can set `UBSAN_OPTIONS=silence_unsigned_overflow=1`. This feature, combined with `-fsanitize-recover=unsigned-integer-overflow`, is particularly useful for providing fuzzing signal without blowing up logs.

Unfortunately GCC only supports `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow`. There's no unsigned version