# How to get a warning in GCC for unsigned integer overflow instead of wrap-around?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Test ENV

- Linux
- Intel x86-64 GCC 8.2.1
- Flags enabled: `-Wextra -Wall -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wcast-qual -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wunreachable-code -Wformat=2 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wformat-security -fstrict-overflow`
- `sizeof(long)` is 8.
- `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Example 1, got a warning, good:

```
long x = 2147483647 * 3;
```

Example 2, no warning, not good:

```
long x = 2147483647U * 3U; // Suffix U
```

or

```
unsigned int a = 2147483647;
unsigned int b = 3;
long x = a*b;
```

Example 3, no warning, but work as expected:

```
long x = 2147483647L * 3L; // Suffix L
```

**In the example 2, I know that it is a wrap-around instead of integer overflow, but these are those cases that the compiler are unable to warn about?**

From the Standard:

## (6.3.1.8)

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then
>   the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand  with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

## (6.5):

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its  (type), the behavior is undefined.

---

Started using Clang with flag `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow` that helps a lot with undesired values from wrap-around. That is not an integer overflow, but not the intended value. Since GCC, until now does not support a warning like this, moving on to Clang.

Comment: FYI: In the terminology of the C standard, `unsigned` integers *never* overflow; they wrap-around.

Comment: In example two you multiply two unsigned integers and the result wrap-around then that result gets stored in a long.

Comment: The value 2147483645 was supose to be the wrap-around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain warning for forgotten cast in arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261433/how-to-obtain-warning-for-forgotten-cast-in-arithmetic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overflow of signed integers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), while unsigned integer overflow is well defined.

For unsigned integers, overflow occurs as if the values were computed modulo one more than the maximum value of the given type.  Put another way, if the type is `n` bits wide, then only the low order `n` bits of the result are retained.  This is not actually overflow but is referred to as **wraparound**.

This is spelled out in [section 6.5p9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The   range   of   nonnegative   values   of   a   signed   integer
>   type   is   a   subrange   of   the corresponding  unsigned  integer 
>   type,  and  the  representation  of  the  same  value  in  each type 
>   is  the  same.  **A  computation  involving  unsigned  operands  can 
>   never  overflow, because  a  result  that  cannot  be  represented  by
>   the  resulting  unsigned  integer  type  is reduced  modulo  the 
>   number  that  is  one  greater  than  the  largest  value  that  can 
>   be represented by the resulting type.**

Because this behavior is well defined, it doesn't make sense for the compiler to trigger a warning.

In the case of your second example:

```
long x = 2147483647U * 3U;
```

The multiplication is done on `unsigned` types, so the mathematical result 6442450941 wraps around to 2147483645, which is within the range of a `long`.  There's no overflow (just wraparound) and no out-of-range conversion, so no warning.

Comment: After your explanation, i got a better idea. But I think the result type of wrap-around is in the range of `int` or `unsigned int`, and not in the range of `long` because since the expression was done on `unsigned int` and that is the resulting type.

Comment: The concept of warning about wrap-around exist in GCC?

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior That's correct, the wraparound occurred using type `unsigned int`, and the resulting value 2147483645 also has that type.  That value is then converted to type `long` before being assigned to `x`.

Comment: so maybe UBSAN can help

Answer (score 0):

Not GCC, but some static analyzer rules would warn about such "overflows".

For instance, both examples 1 & 2 would be flagged by MISRA C checker,
because these overflow in expression with constants - which is indicative of programmer mistake.
2012 Rule 12.4: "Evaluation of constant expressions should not lead to unsigned integer wrap-around."

A more generic case is described by [INT30-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT30-C.+Ensure+that+unsigned+integer+operations+do+not+wrap) in SEI CERT C Coding Standard, which advices to avoid any kind of overflow for secure applications and provides a  list of automatic checkers that honor the rule.