# Compiler warning (or static analysis) for subtraction of unsigned integers?

Tags: c++, g++

Consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 3;
    unsigned int b = 7;

    std::cout << (a - b) << std::endl;  // underflow here!

    return 0;
}
```

In the line starting with `std::cout` an underflow is happening because `a` is lesser than `b` so `a-b` is less than 0, but since `a` and `b` are unsigend so is `a-b`.

Is there a compiler flag (for G++) that gives me a warning when I try to calculate the difference of two unsigend integers?

Now, one could argue that an overflow/underflow can happen in any calculation using any operator. But I think it is more dangerous to apply operator `-` to `unsigend int`s because with unsigned integers this error may happen with quite low (to me: "more common") numbers.

A (static analysis) tool that finds such things would also be great but I much prefer a compiler flag and warning.

Comment: From skimming [the GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and searching for "unsigned" etc, I'm expecting the answer will likely be "no": most relevant-looking flags are for comparisons or conversions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a warning in GCC for unsigned integer overflow instead of wrap-around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837695/how-to-get-a-warning-in-gcc-for-unsigned-integer-overflow-instead-of-wrap-around)

Comment: @Jorengarenar It's close indeed. I still feel a bit uncomfortable with "Because this behavior is well defined, it doesn't make sense for the compiler to trigger a warning." Counter example: unused variables. They are well defined, still gcc may warn about them. So I think this doesn't apply here.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi  The problem with diagnosing potential unsigned integer overflow is false positives on code having a well-defined and *intended* effect that contributes to correct functioning of the program.  The fact that programmers often misunderstand how unsigned overflow works doesn't change the fact that the behaviour is well-defined and often exploited deliberately.   Unused variables aren't ever necessary to correct operation of a program (except in the presence of undefined behaviour, in which case their presence is a side-effect of another unresolved deficiency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC does not (afaict) support it, but [Clang's UBSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) has the following option [**emphasis** mine]:

> `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`: Unsigned integer overflow, where the result of an unsigned integer computation cannot be represented in its type. **Unlike signed integer overflow, this is not undefined behavior, but it is often unintentional.** This sanitizer does not check for lossy implicit conversions performed before such a computation