# C: How to best handle unsigned integers modulo arithmetic ("wrap-around") when using unsigned operands in calculations

Tags: c, integer-overflow

There was this range checking function that required two signed integer parameters:

```
  range_limit(long int lower, long int upper)
```

It was called with `range_limit(0, controller_limit)`. I needed to expand the range check to also include negative numbers up to the 'controller_limit' magnitude.

I naively changed the call to

```
  range_limit(-controller_limit, controller_limit)
```

Although it compiled without warnings, this did not work as I expected.

I missed that `controller_limit` was *unsigned integer*.

In C, simple integer calculations can lead to surprising results. For example these calculations

```
 0u - 1;
```

or more relevant

```
 unsigned int ui = 1;
 -ui;
```

result in 4294967295 of type unsigned int (aka UINT_MAX). As I understand it, this is due to integer conversion rules and modulo arithmetics of unsigned operands [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

By definition, unsigned arithmetic does not overflow but rather "wraps-around". This behavior is well defined, so the compiler will not issue a warning ([at least not gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837695/how-to-get-a-warning-in-gcc-for-unsigned-integer-overflow-instead-of-wrap-around)) if you use these expressions calling a function:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

void f_l(long int li) {

    printf("%li\n", li); // outputs: 4294967295

}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int ui = 1;
    f_l(-ui);
    return 0;
}
```

[Try this code for yourself!](https://rextester.com/XFPJY64094)

So instead of passing a negative value I passed a ridiculously high positive value to the function.

My fix was to cast from unsigned integer into int:

```
    range_limit(-(int)controller_limit, controller_limit);
```

Obviously, integer modulo behavior in combination with integer conversion rules allows for subtle mistakes that are hard to spot especially, as the compiler does not help in finding these mistakes.

As the compiler does not emit any warnings and you can come across these kind of calculations any day, I'd like to know:

**If you have to deal with unsigned operands, how do you best avoid the unsigned integers modulo arithmetic pitfall?**

Note:
While *gcc* does not provide any help in detecting integer modulo arithmetic (at the time of writing), *clang* does. The compiler flag "-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow" will enable detection of modulo arithmetic (using "-Wconversion" is not sufficient), however, not at compile time but at runtime. [Try for yourself!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ub7HY2L7guCCFqQD#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-29)

Further reading:
[Seacord: Secure Coding in C and C++, Chapter 5, Integer Security](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321335724/samplechapter/seacord_ch05.pdf)

Comment: First, specify what you do not like about unsigned arithmetic and specify what behavior you want instead. The wrapping of unsigned arithmetic is generally not considered a pitfall; it was thought to be more beneficial than not, and that is why the C standard specifies it to behave as it does. If your goal is to be able to include unsigned values in arithmetic expressions but have those expressions involve negative results, then you need to convert to a signed integer type. Note that merely casting promiscuously is not a complete solution, as it does not deal with overflow problems.

Comment: Also, choose one tag, C or C++, and delete the other. These are different languages with different answers and solutions. If you need to know about both, ask separate questions for each.

Comment: GCC won't warn you about signed overflow either, so using signed integers doesn't really change the situation.

Comment: So you cast every unsigned integer into `int` in order to make code less well-defined?

Comment: No need to avoid unsigned integers ... simply avoid the wrap-around.    Several techniques, all based on the fundamental idea that you KNOW how big your unsigned int is.  Example 1: My fib code uses uint64_t, and fib(94) is known to wrap-around, so when using uint64_t's, I assert the input is < 94.  Example 2: My hailstone (magic number) code precomputes an upperLimit and asserts that the value is less than the upper limit ...and thus during the test, never wraps around.

Comment: [clang with `-Wsign-conversion` will give you a warning for this](https://godbolt.org/z/PPWvTz):  `the resulting value is always non-negative after implicit conversion [-Wsign-conversion]`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @EricPostpischil: I added a paragraph describing  what motivated me to ask this question. Maybe I was already too much into problem solving instead of phrasing my original problem.

Comment: [MSVC gives you a warning at compile time for many unsigned overflow operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266263/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Using signed integers does not change the situation at all.

A C implementation is under no obligation to raise a run-time warning or error as a response to Undefined Behaviour. Undefined Behaviour is undefined, as it says; the C standard provides absolutely no requirements or guidance about the outcome. A particular implementation can choose any mechanism it sees fit in response to Undefined Behaviour, including explicitly defining the result. (If you rely on that explicit definition, your program is no longer portable to other compilers with different or undocumented behaviour. Perhaps you don't care.)

For example, GCC defines the result of out-of-bounds integer conversions and some bitwise operations in [Implementation-defined behaviour](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) section of its manual.

If you're worried about integer overflow (and there are lots of times you should be worried about it), it's up to you to protect yourself.

For example, instead of allowing:

```
unsigned_counter += 5;
```

to overflow, you could write:

```
if (unsigned_count > UINT_MAX - 5) {
    /* Handle the error */
}
else { 
    unsigned_counter += 5;
}
```

And you should do that in cases where integer overflow will get you into trouble. A common example, which can (and has!) lead to buffer-overflow exploits, comes from checking whether a buffer has enough room for an addition:

```
if (buffer_length + added_length >= buffer_capacity) {
  /* Reallocate buffer or fail*/
}
memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, add_characters, added_length);
buffer_length += added_length;
buffer[buffer_length] = 0;
```

If `buffer_length + added_length` overflows -- in either signed or unsigned arithmetic -- the necessary reallocation (or failure) won't trigger and the `memcpy` will overwrite memory or segfault or do something else you weren't expecting.

It's easy to fix, so it's worth getting into the habit:

```
if (added_length >= buffer_capacity
    || buffer_length >= buffer_capacity - added_length) {
  /* Reallocate buffer or fail*/
}
memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, add_characters, added_length);
buffer_length += added_length;
buffer[buffer_length] = 0;
```

Another similar case where you can get into serious trouble is when you are using a loop and your increment is more than one.

This is safe:

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; ++i) ...
```

This could lead to an infinite loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i += 2) ...
```

The first one is safe -- assuming `i` and `limit` are the same type -- because `i + 1` cannot overflow if `i < limit`. The most it can be is `limit` itself. But no such guarantee can be made about `i + 2`, since `limit` could be `INT_MAX` (or whatever is the maximum value for the integer type being used). Again, the fix is simple: compare the difference rather than the sum.

If you're using GCC and you don't care about full portability, you can use the GCC overflow-detection builtins to help you. They're also documented in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).

Comment: `-pedantic-errors`: Unsigned integers do not overflow, they wrap around, re: *instead of allowing `unsigned_counter += 5;` to overflow...* or as the holy scripture says: "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."

Comment: @antti: it's not a holy scripture; it's a simple document written by our peers, who are talented and doing the best they can but lack divine inspiration, and it needs to be interpreted in that context, with generosity and without reverence. Reification of the ISO standard is the SO equivalent of counting angels dancing on pins, and is equally relevant only to a small circle of self-proclaimed devotees.

Comment: If you intend an addition to be modular, it wraps around and the C semantics are perfect. If you intended the addition to be an addition then the modular addition is a bug (your bug, not C's, but a bug nonetheless.) Describing that bug as "unintended modular reduction" does not, imho, add any clarity; it's an overflow in the common sense that the intended value doesn't fit into the space allocated.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: rereading, that sounded grumpy and I could blame it on the cumulative effect of several days of a painful ear infection, but regardless of the tone I stand by the content. :-)